# annotate ggplot with discrete axis (w/ reproducible example)

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm struggling to find a straightforward solution to fix my plot. The problem stems down to the discrete nature of the x-axis. I want to annotate the plot with text and segments in order to show statistical results.

**1) I want to print the p-value between "Baby" and "Queen" as well as between "Queen" and "Worker"**, but ggplot only allows to annotate above each label, not between them.

**2) Similarly, I want the first two geom_segments to be separated, but ggplot won't let me end the first one at something like "Queen"-0.1 and start the second one at "Queen"+0.1** as it is mixing factors and numbers.

[image: Problematic plot]

Fully reproducible example below, with issues on line 12, 13 and 18:

```
data <- data.frame(Group.1 = rep(c("A","B"),3),Group.2 = c("Baby","Baby","Worker","Worker","Queen","Queen"),
                       value = c(0.18,0.30,0.09,0.25,-0.26,-0.55))

boxplot_candidates <- ggplot(aes(y=value,x=Group.2,fill=Group.2),data= data) + theme_bw() +
      scale_fill_manual(values=c("lightgreen","darkgreen","goldenrod1"),name="") +
      theme(plot.title = element_text(face="bold", size=18, hjust=0)) +
      labs(x="",y="Transcript expression\n(log2-centered TMM-nornalised TPMs)") +
      theme(plot.title=element_text(size=18, vjust=2),legend.position="", legend.text=element_text(size=14),
            axis.text.x = element_text(size = 14, colour = "black"),
            axis.text.y = element_text(size = 14, colour = "black"),
            axis.title.y=element_text(size = 14, colour = "black",vjust=1),
            axis.title.x=element_text(size = 14, colour = "black")) +
      geom_segment(aes(x="Baby",xend="Queen",y=0.7,yend=0.7)) + ##### MAKE XEND SMALLER
      geom_segment(aes(x="Queen",xend="Worker",y=0.7,yend=0.7)) + ##### MAKE XEND LARGER
      geom_segment(aes(x="Baby",xend="Worker",y=1.2,yend=1.2)) +
      ylim(-1.5,1.5) + stat_boxplot(geom ='errorbar') +
      geom_boxplot(notch=F,outlier.shape=NA) +
      geom_point(size=2,position = position_jitter(width = 0.2)) + stat_summary(fun.y=mean, colour = "white",geom="point", size=4) +
      annotate("text", x = as.factor(unique(data$Group.2)),y=c(0.8,0.8,1.3),
               label = c("p < 0.001","p < 0.001","p = 0.89"),family="",fontface = 3,size=4) ##### PRINT "p < 0.001" BETWEEN LABELS

print(boxplot_candidates)
```

Comment: In the future, please boil down your code to a minimal example required to reproduce the issue. Nobody wants to wade through lines and lines of irrelevant theme statements to find the relevant lines that actually cause the problem. Also, please format your code according to an accepted style guide, e.g.: http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Style.html Properly formatted code is easier to read and will more likely get you an answer.

Comment: Okay, duly noted, I left the extra code there in case the solution would have any conflict with it, but it's true that's it's not relevant. Thanks for the advice and the answer!

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Categorical variables are simply placed at locations 1, 2, 3, etc. If you want to reach locations between two categorical variables, you can use coordinates such as 1.2 or 1.5 etc.

Here is a reproducible example with all the irrelevant theme code stripped out:

```
data <- data.frame(Group.1 = rep(c("A", "B"), 3),
                   Group.2 = c("Baby", "Baby", "Worker", "Worker", "Queen", "Queen"),
                   value = c(0.18, 0.30, 0.09, 0.25, -0.26, -0.55))

ggplot(data, aes(y = value, x = Group.2, fill = Group.2)) +
  stat_boxplot(geom = 'errorbar') +
  geom_boxplot(notch = F, outlier.shape = NA) +
  geom_segment(aes(x=1.1, xend=1.9, y=0.7, yend=0.7)) + 
  geom_segment(aes(x=2.1, xend=2.9, y=0.7, yend=0.7)) + 
  geom_segment(aes(x=1.1, xend=2.9, y=1.2, yend=1.2)) +
  geom_point(size = 2, position = position_jitter(width = 0.2)) + 
  stat_summary(fun.y = mean, colour = "white", geom = "point", size = 4) +
  annotate("text",
           x = c(1.5, 2.5, 2),
           y = c(0.8, 0.8, 1.3),
           label = c("p < 0.001", "p < 0.001", "p = 0.89"),
           family = "", fontface = 3, size=4) + 
  scale_fill_manual(values=c("lightgreen", "darkgreen", "goldenrod1"),
                    guide = "none") +
  ylim(-1.5, 1.5) +
  labs(x="", y="Transcript expression\n(log2-centered TMM-nornalised TPMs)") +
  theme_bw()
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the solution! To me the key statement is `geom_boxplot(notch = F, outlier.shape = NA)`